# Por que a função AutoComplete do eclipse não está funcionando dentro do OnClickListener?

Tags: android, eclipse

Estava escrevendo meus códigos normalmente quando um dia percebi que o Eclipse (o programa que estou usando para fazer aplicativos para Android) não está completando minhas palavras, por exemplo: eu tenho uma variável chamada 'Functions', quando eu escrevo 'Func' e aperto Ctrl + Espaço não aparece as opções pra mim escolher.

Mas o estranho é que funciona fora do `OnClickListener`, ou seja, se eu escrever qualquer código dentro do `OnClickListener` o Eclipse não completa, nem os códigos comuns. Antes eu digitava for e apertava Crtl + Espaço e ele me dava sugestões como `Foreach`.

Já tentei marcar as opções Java Proposals nas Configurações do Eclipse, mas continua sem funcionar. Por que isso está acontecendo?

Comment: abre a janela em branco ao pressionar ctrl + espaço ou nem a janela aparece?

Comment: A janela abre e diz "No Default Proposals". Fora do OnClickListener a janela abre e mostra as opções normalmente.

Comment: verifique se a variável que está tentando acessar realmente está acessível dentro do listener, se possível coloque algum código aqui mostrando exatamente como reproduzir o erro

Answer (score 1):

Tente **restaurar as opções padrão** em '`Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced`'

Um exemplo do tipo de dados que você verá nesta tela, podendo diferir do que você tem realmente.

[image: eclipse content assist setting]

(Por [Vadim](http://www.berezniker.com/users/vadim) nessa postagem [blog post " Content Assist Duplicates in Eclipse (Mylyn)"](http://www.berezniker.com/content/pages/java/content-assist-duplicates-eclipse-mylyn):
se houver duplicado as entradas Mylyn, desmarque as duplicadas que não contém a palavra "`(Mylyn)`" em seu nome)

A [página de ajuda do Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/editor/ref-preferences-content-assist-advanced.htm) Define os valores padrões:

> Select the proposal kinds contained in the **'default' content assist list**:
>
> - Other Java Proposals,
> - SWT Template Proposals,
> - Template Proposals,
> - Type Proposals

Fonte:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working